# Реализация Unity client - Unity server - php - mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, unity3d, сеть, клиент-сервер

Добрый день, пишу браузерную игру(не для серьезных целей, просто хобби), возникло несколько вопросов:

1.Пока сделал только авторизацию. Отправляю через юнити клиент данные через POST запрос на php, ответ от php идет через echo, на клиенте в зависимости от ответа выполняется какое-либо действие. Данные с пхп идут в некрасивом виде(echo "ok*$login*$pass"), есть ли другие простые способы получать данные, шифровать необязательно.

2.Например, игрок хочет построить здание, клиент спрашивает у php->mysql хватает ли ресурсов и если да, то строит его, идет запись в бд, о том, что задние у данного игрока теперь есть. А если необходимо подождать 10 минут, пока оно будет строиться? Например при обновлении страницы пользователю можно написать, что здание построится через ((дата начала стройки + время постройки здания) - текущая дата) минут, но когда останется 0 секунд, как записать в бд информацию? Знаю, что в mysql есть планировщик, но это будет неудобно. Можно ли сделать связку Клиент - Сервер - PHP - БД чтобы сервер отвечал за все отложенные действия и также управлял npc/ai в реальном времени, например напал на игрока в рандомное время?(Возможно корутины могут помочь, но не нашел решения, как они работают на сервере)

Comment: 1. Если вы делаете Unity приложение в вебе, используйте REST api. Там можно генерировать красивые ссылки

Comment: 2. При обновлении страницы, у вас перезапустится клиент. Все вычисления и задержки нужно делать на сервере. Не обязательно это должен быть именно другой юнити клиент.